# shell join wrongly matching letters with emoji

Tags: regex, shell, join, unicode

I have two files having each two columns: (Count | Term). Where term column is in Unicode and some terms are emojis.

I am trying to join both files based on term column (second column) using this code:

```
 join -j 2 -o 1.1,1.2,2.1,2.2 <(sort -k2 File1.txt) <(sort -k2 File2.txt) > join_File1_File2.txt
```

When I join the two files I have correct output except some wrong  lines having emoji joined with letters and characters like :

> 11 ∫ 4 ️️️️️
>
> 484 ……… 79 ✊✊✊
>
> 27 ———————————————— 25

I have even some wrong matched emojis like this :

> 39  726

And some wrong matched characters like :

> 2 °′ 1 °☀

Here is a sample of Files : File1, File2 and JoinFile

File1 :

```
   1 ”…………
   1369 i
   1347 …
   1339 it
   8 ⋅⃗
   1322 with
   1 −‾√‾√∴
   1302 are
   1299 your
   1276 my
   39 
   1272 with
   1261 from
   1255 this
   1244 what
```

File 2:

```
   1437 to
   1435 your
   1433 are
   1421 in
   83 ⛔️
   1411 and
   1404 for
   1 ”
   1384 you
   1373 on
   726 
   1347 …
   13 ❤️
   1333 this
   1322 with
```

Join_File1_File2

```
1 ”………… 1 ”
1347 … 1347 …
39  726 
8 ⋅⃗ 83 ⛔️
1 −‾√‾√∴ 13 ❤️
1302 are 1433 are
1255 this 1333 this
1272 with 1322 with
1322 with 1322 with
1299 your 1435 your
```

Comment: Can you include the input files or an extract of them to your question? Otherwise it seems a bit difficult to reproduce your problem in order to solve it

Comment: Sure! I added a sample of the files in the answer.

Comment: `man join` mentions that "comparisons honor the rules specified by 'LC_COLLATE'" which might be your problem as I do not reproduce your problem on ideone : https://ideone.com/mECmOe. What does `locale` output on your machine?